# Feathered edges on image with PIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

How to create a feathered edges effect using pillow?
what i mean by feathered edges is the edges are softened in a way that it fades with the background, something that looks more the following image: [image: this example]

i tried bluring using:

```
im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

but the edges stay sharp.

Comment: I don't think PIL/Pillow has that functionality built in. However, if you can figure out what kernel you have to use for that effect, I think there should be a way to apply it to your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you want is blurring the image. I have the impression  that what you describe is that the image gets more and more transparent towards the edges of the image. You can tune the transparency by creating and manipulating an *alpha* channel. Since you're using Python, here's an example using Python, numpy and the astronaut image from scikit-image. The alpha channel is defined to be constant (no transparency) in the center, zero (transparent) at the edges, with a linear gradient in-between. You could tune the alpha channel for a smoother of sharper transition between no transparency and complete transparency.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data

astro = data.astronaut()
l_row, l_col, nb_channel = astro.shape
rows, cols = np.mgrid[:l_row, :l_col]
radius = np.sqrt((rows - l_row/2)**2 + (cols - l_col/2)**2)
alpha_channel = np.zeros((l_row, l_col))
r_min, r_max = 1./3 * radius.max(), 0.8 * radius.max()
alpha_channel[radius < r_min] = 1
alpha_channel[radius > r_max] = 0
gradient_zone = np.logical_and(radius >= r_min, radius <= r_max)
alpha_channel[gradient_zone] = (r_max - radius[gradient_zone])/(r_max - r_min)
alpha_channel *= 255
feathered = np.empty((l_row, l_col, nb_channel + 1), dtype=np.uint8)
feathered[..., :3] = astro[:]
feathered[..., -1] = alpha_channel[:]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(feathered)
plt.show()
```

[image: Astronaut image with transparency at the edge]